# rgbdslam cannot save .pcd

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and I finally managed to run rgbdslam on my Ubuntu 10.04.

Now the problem is that though I can save node-wide pcd files, but I CANNOT save the whole scene to pcd file. Every time after I clicked save or save as, nothing happened in the destination folder.

Did I miss something?
Could anyone help me with the problem?

Thanks.

Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12586/rgbdslam-cannot-save-.pcd/) by [Jack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1628/jack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I used cloud_to_pcd to subscribe the topic /rgbdslam/batch_cloud and save the scene into pcd.

---

Originally posted by [Jack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1628/jack/) with karma: 16 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is indeed confusing.

Rgbdslam saves the cloud into a file called quicksave.pcd and stores it into its current working directory (cwd). The cwd depends on the way you started it. You can find the cwd by executing `lsof|grep rgbdslam|grep cwd` in a terminal while rgbdslam is running.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-01-11**:
yes indeed. I'll have a look into it. A new version will be released in a few days anyway, so try updating next week.

**Comment by [Jack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1628/jack/) on 2012-01-11**:
Thanks. But still I cannot save .pcd file. I've found the cwd /rgbdslam/bin, but no quicksave.pcd is in it. Save as doesn't work either. So I wonder why node-wide save works, but save or save as doesn't, it's werid, isn't it?